# Db design for data update approval

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, architecture

I'm working on a project where we need to have data entered or updated by some users go through a pending status before being added into 'live data'.

Whilst preparing the data the user can save incomplete records. Whilst the data is in the pending status we don't want the data to affect rules imposed on users editing the live data e.g. a user working on the live data should not run up against a unique contraint when entering the same data that is already in the pending status.

I envisage that sets of data updates will be grouped into a 'data submission' and the data will be re-validated and corrected/rejected/approved when someone quality control the submission.

I've thought about two scenarios with regards to storing the data:

1) Keeping the pending status data in the same table as the live data, but adding a flag to indicate its status. I could see issues here with having to remove contraints or make required fields nullable to support the 'incomplete' status data. Then there is the issue with how to handle updating existing data, you would have to add a new row for an update and link it back to existing 'live' row. This seems a bit messy to me.

2) Add new tables that mirror the live tables and store the data in there until it has been approved. This would allow me to keep full control over the existing live tables while the 'pending' tables can be abused with whatever the user feels he wants to put in there. The downside of this is that I will end up with a lot of extra tables/SPs in the db. Another issue I was thinking about was how might a user link between two records, whereby the record linked to might be a record in the live table or one in the pending table, but I suppose in this situation you could always take a copy of the linked record and treat it as an update?

Neither solutions seem perfect, but the second one seems like the better option to me - is there a third solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your option 2 very much sounds like the best idea. If you want to use referential integrity and all the nice things you get with a DBMS you can't have the pending data in the same table. But there is no need for there to be unstructured data- pending data is still structured and presumably you want the db to play its part in enforcing rules even on this data. Even if you didn't, pending data fits well into a standard table structure.

A separate set of tables sounds the right answer. You can bring the primary key of the row being changed into the pending table so you know what item is being edited, or what item is being linked to.

I don't know your situation exactly so this might not be appropriate, but an idea would be to have a separate table for storing the batch of edits that are being made, because then you can quality control a batch, or submit a batch to live. Each pending table could have a batch key so you know what batch it is part of. You'll have to find a way to control multiple pending edits to the same rows (if you want to) but that doesn't seem too tricky a problem to solve.

I'm not sure if this fits but it might be worth looking into 'Master Data Management' tools such as SQL Server's Master Data Services.

Answer (score 1):

['Unit of work'](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) is a good name for 'data submission'.

You could serialize it to a different place, like (non-relational) document-oriented database, and only save to relational DB on approval.

Depends on how many of live data constraints still need to apply to the unapproved data.

Answer (score 0):

I think second option is better. To manage this, you can use View which will contain both tables and you can work with this structure through view.

---

Another good approach is to use XML column in a separate table to store necessary data(because of unknown quantity/names of columns). You can create just one table with XML column ad column "Type" do determine which table this document is related with.

Answer (score 0):

First scenerio seems to be good.
Add Status column in the table.There is no need to remove Nullable constraint just add one function to check the required fields based on flag like If flag is 1(incomplete) Null is allowed otherwise Not allowed.
regarding second doubt do you want to append the data or update the whole data.